# How can I submit my form if all the validation is correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have just finished getting my validation to work. When I press submit an error box appears with the error relating to the field (e.g special chars used). When all the fields are correct I now need to submit the form. How can I do this? When I press submit nothing happens.

```js
$('button#form-submit').click(function() {
  $.each($("form#all-details input,form#all-details select"),function(a,b){
   if (typeof $(this).attr("data-type") != "undefined") {
    if ($(this).val()=="") {
     dialogWarning('Failure with form submit', '<p>Field <b>"'+$(this).prop("placeholder")+'"</b> must be populated</p>');
     return false;
    };
    if ($(this).attr("data-type")=="text") {
     if (/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i.test($(this).val())===false) {
      dialogWarning('Failure with form submit', '<p>Please do not use special characters in field <b>"'+$(this).prop("placeholder")+'"</b></p>');
      return false;
     };
    } else if ($(this).attr("data-type")=="number") {
     if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())===false){
      dialogWarning('Failure with form submit', '<p>Field <b>"'+$(this).prop("placeholder")+'"</b> must be a number only</p>');
      return false;
     }
    }
   };
  });
  /* Submit form */
    });
```

```html
<form id="all-details" onSubmit="return false;" action="add_Consignee.php" method="POST">
 Consignee:</br>
  <input type="text" name="Consignee" id="text" data-type="text" placeholder="Consignee"></br>
 Name:</br>
  <input type="text" name="Name" data-type="text" placeholder="Name" ></br>
  <input type="number" name="Forwarder_Contact_Number" data-type="number" placeholder="Forwarder Contact Number"></br> 
    Any Special Requirements?</br>
  <input type="text" name="Special_Req" data-type="text" placeholder="Any Special Requirements"></br> </br>  
  <button id="form-submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: **Note:** Your `return false` is just going to break out of the `$.each` and not the submit handler. You could just do a `$('#all-details').submit()` (outside `$.each`) to submit the form; that is after a flag that will be validated and set inside each of those validation.

Comment: `$('#all-details').submit()` should do the trick, after your validation is complete.

Comment: That doesn't work sorry to both of you.

Comment: @JIMMYTHECODE It doesn't because of your `onSubmit="return false;"` in the form tag.. You need to get rid of it to submit.

Comment: but then the form will submit even if it has error..?

Comment: @JIMMYTHECODE Remove the `return false` and use `event.preventDefault`. `$('button#form-submit').click(function(event)...` and then inside as your first line `event.preventDefault()`. That should prevent submission until you validate.

Comment: @JIMMYTHECODE You have a handler to stop the form from submitting.. so it wouldn't.. See Tricky12 comment

Comment: @Tricky12 I dont understand where im putting what your saying... Can you do a snipped or fiddle please.

Comment: @JIMMYTHECODE Sure! Here is a simplified JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3ggzkcss/1/.

Comment: Just added your code and it didn't change anything sorry

Comment: You removed `onSubmit="return false"`, correct? Nothing will submit if you have that.

Comment: Yep i took that out as well

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle with a 100% fully functional form, minus your `dialogWarning` calls, which I replaced with a simple alert. https://jsfiddle.net/3ggzkcss/2/

Comment: I get the error = jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on mine

Comment: Your issue must be elsewhere in your code. I copied yours exactly, made the changes I mentioned and then commented out your `dialogWarning`s, and the JSFiddle works perfect for me.

Comment: You were right! got it working now. THANKYOUUUUU

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear and no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do like this:

```
$('button#form-submit').click(function() {
var _errors = [];
$.each($("form#all-details input,form#all-details select"),function(a,b){
    if (typeof $(this).attr("data-type") != "undefined") {
        if ($(this).val()=="") {
            _errors.push('<p>Field <b>"'+$(this).prop("placeholder")+'"</b> must be populated</p>');
        };
        if ($(this).attr("data-type")=="text") {
            if (/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i.test($(this).val())===false) {
                _errors.push('<p>Please do not use special characters in field <b>"'+$(this).prop("placeholder")+'"</b></p>');
                _errors++;
            };
        } else if ($(this).attr("data-type")=="number") {
            if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())===false){
                _errors.push('<p>Field <b>"'+$(this).prop("placeholder")+'"</b> must be a number only</p>');
                _errors++;
            }
        }
    };
});
if (_errors.length > 0) {
    dialogWarning('Failure with form submit', _errors.join(' ');
    return false;
} else {
    $(this).submit();
}
/* Submit form */
});
```

This way it'll treat multiple errors at once, and you'll have more control over the click event.

Comment: You have got rid of dialogWarning this my validation error pop up that I need

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your button has type="submit" added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your validation inside a function, eg

```
function validate() {
// validation code
 }
```

Then call it in your form: `onSubmit="validate()"`